# Applications are not complete on Spark History Server

Tags: apache-spark

`Spark History Server` runs fine and I can use REST api to get jsons. I"m using --master yarn and --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true. I do make sure to call spark.stop at the end. However, applications still show up as incomplete all the time in the History Server. And these incomplete applications do not show any jobs performed.

```
"completed" : false
```

I've tested with spark-submit and with spark-shell
Any ideas why? I would like to collect the stats on jobs

VK